# How to UnitTest this method properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, memorystream

I have a method (below) that is called from a controller in a MVC application which then outputs an excel file.

Method:

```
public static void ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<dynamic> data, string bookName, string sheetName)
{
    XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
    worksheet.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(data);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format(@"attachment;filename={0}.xlsx", bookName.Replace(" ", "_")));

    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(memStream);
        memStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        memStream.Close();
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Controller:

```
[ActionName("ExportData")]
public ActionResult ExportData()
{
    ExcelExport.ExportToExcel(_dbaccess.GetAllData()), "Workbook", "Worksheet");

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

How can I test this method?

Comment: This method is coupled too tightly to `HttpContext`. Which makes it a little difficult to test but not impossible. Which method you want tested. `ExportToExcel` or `ExportData`. What test framework are you using?

Comment: Ideally both but the most important would be `ExportData`

Comment: You say test properly (opinion based) what do you want to test exactly. I have an idea but these are things you need to state/know before going down the path of testing stuff.

Comment: Really what I want to do is test that the controller returns the correct Redirect and that the `ExportToExcel` with a quantifiable data param, would Mocking work here?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: with some refactoring you can make it testable because as it stands the things you will want to mock complicate matters. As a rule DON'T MOCK TYPES YOU DON'T OWN. using `HttpContext` just adds to that complication. I'm currently drafting up an answer for you.

Comment: Wow. After my long winded answer I just realized you have a major issue with your action. Your redirect makes exporting the excel mute as the context will be lost on the redirect. My answer should still be of some use to you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to refactor that method to make it a little more testable. There are just too many concerns mixed up in there to make testing it easy. (My opinion).

Strip out workbook generation, which can belong to the same class or to some dependency

```
public interface IGetWorkBook {
    XLWorkbook GetWorkBook(IEnumerable<dynamic> data, string sheetName);
}
```

where the implementation can look like exactly what you have in your original method.

```
public XLWorkbook GetWorkBook(IEnumerable<dynamic> data, string sheetName) {    
    XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
    worksheet.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(data);    
}
```

Next you need to abstract away the tight coupling to `HttpContext`

there are some good articles about getting around testing with `HttpContext`

[Don't mock HttpContext](https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2010/08/19/Dont-mock-HttpContext) **He doesn't like to be mocked**! :)

The question you have to ask is `what am I trying to achieve?`. In this case we want to save the workbook to something. Yes in this case its the `HttpContext` response, but it could be something else. For that we need an abstraction

```
public interface IWriteWorkbook {
    void Write(XLWorkbook workbook, string bookName); 
}
```

which you can later include in a derived class the `HttpContext` you so love to use.

```
void Write(XLWorkbook workbook, string bookName) {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format(@"attachment;filename={0}.xlsx", bookName.Replace(" ", "_")));

    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(memStream);
        memStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        memStream.Close();
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

This too can be improved upon but that's out side of this post.

Your refactored method could look something like this after all the changes.

```
public interface IExcelExporter {
    void ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<dynamic> data, string bookName, string sheetName);
}

public class ExcelExport : IExcelExporter {
    IGetWorkBook workbookgGetter;
    IWriteWorkbook workbookWriter;

    public ExcelExport (IGetWorkBook workbookgGetter,IWriteWorkbook workbookWriter) {
        this.workbookgGetter = workbookgGetter;
        this.workbookWriter = workbookWriter;
    }

    public void ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<dynamic> data, string bookName, string sheetName)
    {
        XLWorkbook workbook = workbookgGetter.GetWorkBook(data, sheetName);
        void workbookWriter.Write(workbook,bookName);        
    }    
}
```

Ok, phew...that's a lot. Didn't think it would be that much did you? But it's worth it in the end. I think? :)

Now we need target the controller.

```
public class MyExcelController: Controller {

    public MyExcelController(IExcelExporter exporter){
        ExcelExport = exporter;
    }

    IExcelExporter ExcelExport{get; private set;}

    [ActionName("ExportData")]
    public ActionResult ExportData()
    {
        ExcelExport.ExportToExcel(_dbaccess.GetAllData(), "Workbook", "Worksheet");

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Note how after all this that the original controller action has not changed while everything around it has :) sweet!!.

Now we are ready to mock and test to our hearts content.

You can test `IGetWorkBook.GetWorkBook`

You can test `IWriteWorkbook.Write`

You can test `ExcelExport.ExportToExcel`

to make sure they all operate as expected.

Comment: Wow that is some response, thanks so much. So useful.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably split the method up more. Create a method that returns a byte[] that generates the byte array that represents the file:

```
public static byte[] ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<dynamic> data, string bookName, string sheetName)
```

And then create a method that actually saves to disk:

```
public static bool SaveFileToDisk(byte[] file, string path)
```

You can then test the `ExportToExcel` method asserting that it returns a known byte[]